# Inconsistent number of samples error in SVM accuracy calculation

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to calculate the accuracy score, of a SVM using Laplacian kernel (as a pre-computed kernel). However, I'm getting the error as below when I try to calculate the accuracy score.

My code :

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import laplacian_kernel

#Load the iris data
iris_data = load_iris()

#Split the data and target
X = iris_data.data
y = iris_data.target

#Convert X and y to a numpy array
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

#Perform train-test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

#Using Laplacian kernel - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#laplacian-kernel
K = np.array(laplacian_kernel(X_train, gamma=.5))
svm = SVC(kernel='precomputed').fit(K, np.ravel(y_train))
pred_y = svm.predict(K)

#Print accuracy score - here is where the error is happening.
print(accuracy_score(y_test, pred_y))
```

When I run this code, I'm getting error as shown below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Research/Src/Laplace.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, pred_y))
  File "/Users/user/miniforge3/envs/user_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/miniforge3/envs/user/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 202, in accuracy_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/Users/user/miniforge3/envs/user/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 83, in _check_targets
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/Users/user/miniforge3/envs/user/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 262, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [45, 105]
```

So how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Instead of using some local file with the iris data, please post a fully reproducible example using the iris data from scikit-learn. Plus, we have standard notation for comments in the code, we don't use anything we may like (edited).

Comment: @desertnaut: Edited the code with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculated `pred_y` using your train inputs which has 105 elements and `y_test` has 45 elements.

You need to add a step:

```
#user3046211's code

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import laplacian_kernel

#Load the iris data
iris_data = load_iris()

#Split the data and target
X = iris_data.data
y = iris_data.target

#Convert X and y to a numpy array
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

#Perform train-test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

#Using Laplacian kernel - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#laplacian-kernel
K = np.array(laplacian_kernel(X_train, gamma=.5))
svm = SVC(kernel='precomputed').fit(K, np.ravel(y_train))
pred_y = svm.predict(K)

#Print accuracy score - here is where the error is happening.
print(accuracy_score(y_test, pred_y))

# NEW CODE STARTS HERE
K_test = np.array(laplacian_kernel(X=X_test,Y=X_train, gamma=.5))
pred_y_test = svm.predict(K_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, pred_y_test))
```

Comment: I added the lines which you mentioned, but it's throwing a value error 
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 45 should be equal to 105, the number of samples at training time. Can you show it using my code, so that it will be more clear?

Comment: I plugged in all of your code; the new code just goes at end.  The issue with my original addition is that the kernel needs to be precomputed with pairwise distance between the test AND train data on inference.